# Is there ready to use method to rename C# operator names to symbols

Tags: c#, operators, rename

C# defines all operators as static methods. This is also the name which they get in reflection. For display purposes i am looking for a renaming method which transforms all those strings into their c# code representation like +, -, *, /, >>, <<, ... and so on.

EDIT: Of course its easy to code it. but i am looking for an official .NET method or another solution which is somewhere out there.

```
op_Implicit
op_explicit
op_Addition
op_Subtraction
op_Multiply
op_Division
op_Modulus
op_ExclusiveOr
op_BitwiseAnd
op_BitwiseOr
op_LogicalAnd
op_LogicalOr
op_Assign
op_LeftShift
op_RightShift
op_SignedRightShift
op_UnsignedRightShift
op_Equality
op_GreaterThan
op_LessThan
op_Inequality
op_GreaterThanOrEqual
op_LessThanOrEqual
op_MultiplicationAssignment
op_SubtractionAssignment
op_ExclusiveOrAssignment
op_LeftShiftAssignment
op_ModulusAssignment
op_AdditionAssignment
op_BitwiseAndAssignment
op_BitwiseOrAssignment
op_Comma
op_DivisionAssignment
op_Decrement
op_Increment
op_UnaryNegation
op_UnaryPlus
op_OnesComplement
```

Comment: You could use a dictionary mapping of names to operators?

Comment: Why do you expect that there is a  builtin method that returns an operator symbol for an operator method name? Use a dictionary as suggested.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - and how about discerning op_GreaterThan and op_RightShift ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: OP has not stated that he needs to now the method-name by symbol but to get the symbol by name.

Comment: Right, I misread the desired direction here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Umm `>` for greater than and `>>` for right shift. Apart from that I don't see your point.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel it's quite clear that i can roll it on my own. but i am looking for an "official" or already coded solution.

Comment: @thalm, so, how did you solved that? just curious :)

Comment: @igorushi just by hand, as you pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all there are just 38 items ([reference for all symbols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229032(v=vs.100).aspx))

```
var map = new Dictionary<string,string>{
{"op_Implicit",""},
{"op_explicit",""},
{"op_Addition","+"},
{"op_Subtraction","-"},
{"op_Multiply","*"},
{"op_Division","/"},
{"op_Modulus","%"},
{"op_ExclusiveOr","^"},
{"op_BitwiseAnd","&"},
{"op_BitwiseOr","|"},
{"op_LogicalAnd","&&"},
{"op_LogicalOr","||"},
{"op_Assign","="},
{"op_LeftShift","<<"},
{"op_RightShift",">>"},
{"op_SignedRightShift",""},
{"op_UnsignedRightShift",""},
{"op_Equality","=="},
{"op_GreaterThan",">"},
{"op_LessThan","<"},
{"op_Inequality","!="},
{"op_GreaterThanOrEqual",">="},
{"op_LessThanOrEqual","<="},
{"op_MultiplicationAssignment","*="},
{"op_SubtractionAssignment","-="},
{"op_ExclusiveOrAssignment","^="},
{"op_LeftShiftAssignment","<<="},
{"op_ModulusAssignment","%="},
{"op_AdditionAssignment","+="},
{"op_BitwiseAndAssignment","&="},
{"op_BitwiseOrAssignment","|="},
{"op_Comma",","},
{"op_DivisionAssignment","/="},
{"op_Decrement","--"},
{"op_Increment","++"},
{"op_UnaryNegation","-"},
{"op_UnaryPlus","+"},
{"op_OnesComplement","~"}
};
```

Comment: well, fair enough. but i still ask myself whether there is a method hidden somewhere in the .NET framework. thanks though...

Comment: And there you go, this list has errors, you mixed the logical and bitwise operators... that's what i mean.